# Angular2 throws compiler error to something run in a subscribe()

Tags: angular

I have a textarea on which I want to listen to keyup events. Everything works fine except that Angular2 throws an error compile-time (not runtime).

The error:

> error TS2339: Property 'target' does not exist on type '{}'.

The code:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.nativeElement, 'keyup')
          .debounceTime(500)
          .subscribe(event => this.hasError = !this.isValidJSON(event.target.value));
```

Obviously the error is suggesting that `event` is an empty object.

As I said, the keyup event and my application runs fine but this error is annoying and I want to get rid of it. How can it complain about event being an empty object **during compile-time**? It has never even been run, and during run-time everything works.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(event)`? Obviously, what you get as `event` is not a DOM event.

Comment: As I said, this is during compile-time, so I console.log anything.

Comment: I see. Sorry, didn't read properly. What about casting like `.subscribe(event => this.hasError = !this.isValidJSON((<Event>event).target.value));` or `Observable<Event>.fromEvent(`

Comment: Or try to specify the type of the event : `subscribe(event: Event => /*...*/);`

Comment: Neither of those suggestions work. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to the appropriate type:

I suggest you cast to `KeyboardEvent` (which inherits from ES6's `Event`) or, if you just want to get rid of the error use `any`:

```
subscribe((event: KeyboardEvent) => ...);
```

or

```
subscribe((event: any) => ...);
```

If you just use `Event` there might be a mixup with `Event` automatically imported from `@angular/router`.

[[image: 1]]